# working with lists in grails

Tags: list, grails, groovy

I am trying to get every instance of a domain where there user is equal to current logged in user.
My code at the minute is:

```
def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    if (lookupPerson().username == "admin"){
         adminList(max)
    }
    else{

        def childList = []
        def i = 1
     Child.list().each(){
         if(Child.get(i).user.username == lookupPerson().username){
             def child = Child.get(i)
             childList.add(child)
         }
          i++
     }
        [childInstanceList: childList.list(params), childInstanceTotal: childList.count()]
    }


}
```

This gives me the following error
No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.list() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap) values: [[action:list, controller:child, max:10]] Possible solutions: last(), first(), asList(), toList(), is(java.lang.Object), wait()

I'm sure there must be an easier and better way of doing this.
any ideas?

Comment: The problem is with the `childList.list(params)` call on the last line - what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: in my Child domain i have the User who created the Child. I am wanting to list all Children who have been created by the currently logged in user.

Comment: @Sagarmichael Which you should have in the list.  You then seem to try and call `list(params)` on this list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do what you're after with a criteria query:

```
def childList = Child.createCriteria().list(params) {
  user {
    eq('username', lookupPerson().username)
  }
}
```

If your `params` has pagination parameters then the "total" will be available as `childList.totalCount`, you don't need to calculate it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Add the domain classes, please.

But anyway, I suppose, your "else" branch should lokk like:

```
Child.list().each {
    if( it.user.username == lookupPerson().person ) {
        childList.add( it )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def childList = Child.findByUser(lookupPerson.username)
```

or

```
def childList = Child.withCriteria {
    eq("user", lookupPerson)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Child and User class... why not do this?...

```
class Child {
    //properties
    User user
}

class User {
   //properties

  def getChilds() {
     Child.findAllByUser(this)
  }
}
```

Then you only need call this on your controller, service, view:

```
def user = User.findByUsername(params.username)
def childs = user.childs //or user.getChilds()
```